# ASP.NET Core : AddAreaPageRoute - parameter more than one time in the route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

What I am trying to do is something like this:

```
services
   .AddRazorPages()
   .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
   {
       options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Products", "/DownloadDoc", "Products/{keycode}/{keycode}-document.pdf");
   });
```

So if `keycode` was `productTest`, the url generated should be:

```
Products/productTest/productTest-document.pdf
```

Not sure if it is possible or not?

Currently it throws this error:

> RoutePatternException: The route parameter name 'keycode' appears more than one time in the route template.

I have even tried things like this:

```
options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Products", "/DownloadDoc", "Products/{keycode2:keycode}/{keycode}-document.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

actually, the problem is the naming problem.
The URL format doesn't support multi able same parameters name.

Can you try like this

```
       options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Products", "/DownloadDoc", "Products/{keycode}/{keycode2}-document.pdf");
```

Comment: problem with this approach is that would need to add a keycode2 onto every downloadDoc link

Answer (score 0):

According to your route rule `Products/{keycode}/{keycode}-document.pdf`, this rule means it will match the two part for the url with the same parameter.  This is not expected inside the asp.net core rule mapping rule.

If you think this two parameter should be the same, you could make a check by using a specific middleware or else.

If you make sure this two parameters will be the same, I think just one keycode is enough.

Comment: Ok will see if going down the middleware approach will help, as currently cant think of another way. not even away to tell .net to ignore one of the params and just treat it as a string value, because will have the other keycode param to get the value from

Comment: Yes, two parameter will also work for your requirement.